# How to unlock the Knife in the Dark mission?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

I can't get to Cirith Ungol to play the next mission called Knife in the Dark.
The data installation is stuck at 78%. What do I have to complete in the game to unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have just finished Act I, "*you have to recruit Brûz and take over the Nurnen Fortress before you can go elsewhere*", according to [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/356190/discussions/0/1484358860940358673/#c1484358860940379993).

Otherwise, because you mention your data installation being stuck, it might be that your game - the Cirith Ungol area, specifically - has not yet been downloaded completely. Give it more time, preferably without playing, and it should continue downloading until it is playable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will do as you say and give it  some time. if it does not work, I will get back to you

Comment: @ped You're welcome, and I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: @ped So, I assume this didn't work? Did you recruit Brûz and take over the Nurnen Fortress? How far are you into the game?

Comment: Hello again. I am at the point where I need to go to cirith ungol to do the mission knife in the dark but for some reason it says that the content has not yet been installed.

Comment: I have not yet finished Act 1 because it does not let me to progress to the rest of the game.